# Spring Boot MongoDb filter only by time

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, datetime, filter

Actually I'm storing appointments in a MongoDB collection. Each appointment has a **start and an end date**.

Example: `startDate: 2021-03-02T06:00:00.000+00:00, endDate: 2021-03-02T07:00:00.000+00:00`

Actually I have a small framework which is able to create a complex criteria for me to filter out the appointments by other attributes. I would like to keep using it. This framework creates a list of criteria based on a GET API's request parameters. At the end it combines all the criterias with AND operation.

Actually we are able to get all the appointments between two dates by something like:

```
/**
   * The appointment is scheduled after the given time.
   * 
   * @param time
   * @return
   */
  public AppointmentFilter scheduledAfter(OffsetDateTime time) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(time);
    return this.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator( //
        Criteria.where("startDate").gte(time), //
        Criteria.where("endDate").gt(time)));
  }

  /**
   * The appointment is scheduled before the given time.
   * 
   * @param time
   * @return
   */
  public AppointmentFilter scheduledBefore(OffsetDateTime time) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(time);
    return this.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator( //
        Criteria.where("startDate").lte(time), //
        Criteria.where("endDate").lt(time)));
  }
```

Actually we have to provide the possibility to narrow the returned appointment list by time periods as well.

This means that I have to get all the appointments between two dates (by the above methods) which are planned **between 09:00 and 10:00**.

To do that I have to create a Criteria which considers just and only the time (hour, minutes, seconds, etc) from the stored appointment's start and end date.

I found some kind of extremly complicated solutions by aggregations but the framework does not support the aggregations (yet). And while I would be able to aggregate the start and end date' hour, minute, etc separately the required criteria would be extremly complex.

Is there any other method to create a `Criteria` (just as above) which considers just the time of a date ?

I would like to use `java.time.OffsetTime` as input for them. That would be the reasonable input.

Thank you so much for your help, and I wish you a very nice day!